# doxygen error state 20 with fortran code - linux

Tags: doxygen

I was searching the web for help and didn't find any. Thats why I thought it might be a good idea to document my problem here.

I had the following problem while documenting a really old (15-20 years) FORTRAN-Code with doxygen. I have a file with the same filename as the subroutine in it. And some of these files gave me an error:

---

Error in file FILENAME line: XX, state: 20

---

I didn't figure out, what the error state 20 is. After some digging into the code I did find the problem. I have a commentary fortran line like :

> **C  ECHANGE EN CONVECTION AUTOUR D' UNE SPHERE**

The problem here is the apostrophe mark (') in a commentary code line. Doxygen seems to interpret an apostrophe mark as doxygen syntax and not a commentary line FORTRAN code. I changed the line into :

> **C  ECHANGE EN CONVECTION AUTOUR D UNE SPHERE**

and now everything works fine!

Comment: Can you rewrite this in Question and Answer format? Ie post it as a question, and post the answer as an answer? At the moment it is more like a blog post than a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Please show some code and also mention the version of doxygen you are using. Also when FILENAME is given give that filename as from this one might even deduct what the problem can be.